# Can funds be recovered if sent to the same address twice

Tags: transactions, cross-chain-recovery

I signed up with Swapnex.io and sent an initial deposit of USDT TRC20 to test the transaction which went through quickly. Thereafter I sent a much larger sum, however I did not realize that the original address was still displayed, and I sent the second amount to the same address. It was verified on the hash. It has not shown up on my account in Swapnex, and I understand that one must always send to a new address. I am not getting a clear answer about how these funds can be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

Unless specified otherwise, some platforms tend to issue a new address per transaction. Always, consult the behaviour of a platform's address issuance prior to submitting transactions.

You should contact the platform's support and inquire if your funds can be retrieved.

Comment: Thanks Carlo. I understand this now. Mostly I am interested in the mechanics to determine whether the platform can access these funds. If used once on their platform doesn’t this address reside with them such that they can access?

Comment: It really depends, some platforms have different approaches to their security depending on the infrastructure used within. For example, Shakepay, a popular Canadian exchange. They can retrieve USDT, however they can't or more specifically they won't retrieve other  tokens within the same address. I know it's dumb, lol.

Comment: I once did something similar with another Canadian exchange, namely BitBuy and forgot to specify the transfer was for my account. Their support was able to sort it out and credit my account fairly quickly.